# C# add custom font by ttf

Tags: c#, fonts, system.drawing, truetype, system.drawing.graphics

I use **System.Drawing.Graphics** to draw some text.

I want to add custom font for that.
In this case I have to create **System.Drawing.Font**.

How can I create **System.Drawing.Font** by using ***.ttf** file with custom font?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use  [PrivateFontCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.text.privatefontcollection.aspx) class.

[Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y505zzfw.aspx) is full details about how to use it