# Is there a way to create ttf file from Font and FontFamily in C#?

Tags: c#, truetype

I have this code:

```cs
PrivateFontCollection collection = new PrivateFontCollection();

collection.AddFontFile(@"C:\Projects\MyProj\free3of9.ttf");

FontFamily fontFamily = new FontFamily("Free 3 of 9", collection);
Font font = new Font(fontFamily, height);
```

Now, how can I save the `.ttf` file, using collection, fontFamily, and font?

Comment: what do you mean by saving? on disk?

Comment: yeah, for example, like file "font.ttf"

Comment: you can use `File.WriteAllText()` method

Comment: but how? Can you write small example, please? My problem that i don't have access to existing ".ttf" file, i have only PrivateFontCollection, FontFamily and Font. And i don't understand how to use File.WriteAllText() with that...((

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C# add custom font by ttf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37809860/c-sharp-add-custom-font-by-ttf)

Comment: Unfortunately no, there is a download from ttf, but I need the reverse action...(

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.